# Named Set MDX Error

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm having this error after creating a named set in SSAS to retrieve the last 10 weeks from the first day of current week. the expression I used is :

```
strtoset(
  "LASTPERIODS(
      10
     ,[AxeTemps].[Semaine].&["+Format(NOW()-WEEKDAY(NOW(),2),'yyyyMMdd')+"]")
```

My date hierarchy has the following members structure :

```
[AxeTemps].[Semaine].&[20000101].
```

I can't get this work, any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have convert the a member first, then you can pass it to the LastPeriods():

```
LastPeriods(
    10,
    StrToMember("[AxeTemps].[Semaine].&[" + Format(NOW()-WEEKDAY(NOW(),2),'yyyyMMdd') + "]")
)
```